# search key word from csv file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a CSV file with a key and a value under it:
key
pants. 
I want jmeter to read this value from the file and search for it in the search field. This is what I did but it didn't work.[image]

The error I got when running: 
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in query at index 94: http://www.shopyourway.com//search/products?filters=availability%3A1&allowRedirection=true&q=${key}

Response headers:

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

So What should I put in the path for it to work?

Comment: Can you show the image of CSV file config?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- In "**Server Name or IP**", remove "**/**
- In "**Send Parameters with the request**" delete the field "**q**" & "**${key}**", you are passing the value 2 times which is not correct.

these changes will work if "**CSV Data Config**" has been configured correctly.

Hope this will help.